# Sand and Fluid Cellular Automata

Tags: c++, game-physics

I have been struggling all day to get the fluid to work in my sand and fluid cellular automata simulation. Ive searched the web for info on how I could solve my issue but I cannot seem to fix it as Ive been at this all day.

My issue is that whenever a water cell reaches the end of the window, or collides with another water cell, it and the cell next to it flashes on and off.

here is my code

```cpp
struct Cell {
    
    int x, y;
    int size;
    int type;
    bool moved = false;
    int dir = -1;
    sf::RectangleShape rect;

    Cell(int cxPos, int cyPos, int cSize, int cType, int cDir = -1) {
        x = cxPos;
        y = cyPos;
        size = cSize;
        type = cType;
        dir = cDir;
        sf::Color color = sf::Color::Black;
        if (type == 1) color = sf::Color(255, 255, 0);
        if (type == 2) color = sf::Color(0, 0, 255);

        rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(size), static_cast<float>(size)));
        rect.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(x), static_cast<float>(y)));
        setColor(color);
    }
    void setColor(sf::Color color) 
    {
        rect.setFillColor(color);
    }
    void update(std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>& array)
    {
        int px = x/size;
        int py = y/size;
        int below = array[px][py + 1].type;
        int bottomLeft = (px > 0) ? array[px - 1][py + 1].type : -1;  // Check if left neighbor exists
        int bottomRight = (px + 1 < static_cast<int>(array.size())) ? array[px + 1][py + 1].type : -1;  // Check if right neighbor exists
        int left = (px - 1 >= 0) ? array[px - 1][py].type : -1;
        if (type == 1 && py + 1 < static_cast<int>(array[px].size()) && !moved)
        {
            if(below == 0) 
            {
                array[px][py+1].type = 1;
                array[px][py].type = 0;
                array[px][py+1].moved = true;
            }
            if (below == 1) {
                if (bottomLeft == 0) {
                    array[px][py].type = 0;
                    array[px-1][py+1].type = 1;
                    array[px-1][py+1].moved = true;
                }
                else if (bottomRight == 0) {
                    array[px][py].type = 0;
                    array[px+1][py+1].type = 1;
                    array[px + 1][py + 1].moved = true;;
                }
            }
        }
        if (type == 2 && py + 1 < static_cast<int>(array[px].size()) && !moved) 
        {   
            
            if (below == 0) {
                array[px][py + 1].type = 2;
                array[px][py].type = 0;
                array[px][py + 1].moved = true;
            }

            if (below != 0) 
            {
                int dirIsGood = (dir > 0) ? ((px + dir < static_cast<int>(array.size())) ? 1 : -1) : (px + dir >= 0 ? 1 : -1);

                if (dirIsGood == 1) 
                {
                    if (array[px + dir][py].type == 2) 
                    {
                        array[px+dir][py].moved = true;
                        array[px][py].moved = true;
                        array[px+dir][py].dir *= -1;
                        array[px][py].dir *= -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        array[px + dir][py].type = 2;
                        array[px][py].type = 0;
                        array[px + dir][py].moved = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dir *= -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

the main code is here for the water cell is here, where it gets the current Cell type, which is 2, which makes it water. then it checks if it can fall. and can move to avoid moving the cell again in the same iteration.

```cpp
if (type == 2 && py + 1 < static_cast<int>(array[px].size()) && !moved) 
{   
            
    if (below == 0) {
        array[px][py + 1].type = 2;
        array[px][py].type = 0;
        array[px][py + 1].moved = true;
    }

    if (below != 0) 
    {
        int dirIsGood = (dir > 0) ? ((px + dir < static_cast<int>(array.size())) ? 1 : -1) : (px + dir >= 0 ? 1 : -1);

        if (dirIsGood == 1) 
        {
            if (array[px + dir][py].type == 2) 
            {
                array[px+dir][py].moved = true;
                array[px][py].moved = true;
                array[px+dir][py].dir *= -1;
                array[px][py].dir *= -1;
            }
            else {
                array[px + dir][py].type = 2;
                array[px][py].type = 0;
                array[px + dir][py].moved = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            dir *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the entire code source I am working on just incase this is helpful. Maybe im doing something out of order or something?

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Main.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Cell {
    
    int x, y;
    int size;
    int type;
    bool moved = false;
    int dir = -1;
    sf::RectangleShape rect;

    Cell(int cxPos, int cyPos, int cSize, int cType, int cDir = -1) {
        x = cxPos;
        y = cyPos;
        size = cSize;
        type = cType;
        dir = cDir;
        sf::Color color = sf::Color::Black;
        if (type == 1) color = sf::Color(255, 255, 0);
        if (type == 2) color = sf::Color(0, 0, 255);

        rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(size), static_cast<float>(size)));
        rect.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(x), static_cast<float>(y)));
        setColor(color);
    }
    void setColor(sf::Color color) 
    {
        rect.setFillColor(color);
    }
    void update(std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>& array)
    {
        int px = x/size;
        int py = y/size;
        int below = array[px][py + 1].type;
        int bottomLeft = (px > 0) ? array[px - 1][py + 1].type : -1;  // Check if left neighbor exists
        int bottomRight = (px + 1 < static_cast<int>(array.size())) ? array[px + 1][py + 1].type : -1;  // Check if right neighbor exists
        int left = (px - 1 >= 0) ? array[px - 1][py].type : -1;
        if (type == 1 && py + 1 < static_cast<int>(array[px].size()) && !moved)
        {
            if(below == 0) 
            {
                array[px][py+1].type = 1;
                array[px][py].type = 0;
                array[px][py+1].moved = true;
            }
            if (below == 1) {
                if (bottomLeft == 0) {
                    array[px][py].type = 0;
                    array[px-1][py+1].type = 1;
                    array[px-1][py+1].moved = true;
                }
                else if (bottomRight == 0) {
                    array[px][py].type = 0;
                    array[px+1][py+1].type = 1;
                    array[px + 1][py + 1].moved = true;;
                }
            }
        }
        if (type == 2 && py + 1 < static_cast<int>(array[px].size()) && !moved) 
        {   
            
            if (below == 0) {
                array[px][py + 1].type = 2;
                array[px][py].type = 0;
                array[px][py + 1].moved = true;
            }

            if (below != 0) 
            {
                int dirIsGood = (dir > 0) ? ((px + dir < static_cast<int>(array.size())) ? 1 : -1) : (px + dir >= 0 ? 1 : -1);

                if (dirIsGood == 1) 
                {
                    if (array[px + dir][py].type == 2) 
                    {
                        array[px+dir][py].moved = true;
                        array[px][py].moved = true;
                        array[px+dir][py].dir *= -1;
                        array[px][py].dir *= -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        array[px + dir][py].type = 2;
                        array[px][py].type = 0;
                        array[px + dir][py].moved = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    dir *= -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};


int main() {

    const int width = 600;
    const int height = 600;
    const int size = 30;
    const int blockSize = width / size;
    


    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Thing!");
    window.setFramerateLimit(5);
    //init cell array
    std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> array(size, std::vector<Cell>(size, Cell(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    // put a cell in the array
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = Cell(x*blockSize, y*blockSize, blockSize, 0);
        }
    }

    array[2][2].type = 2;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            {
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                    for (auto& row : array)
                    {
                        for (auto& currCell : row)
                        {
                            sf::FloatRect cellBounds = currCell.rect.getGlobalBounds();
                            if (cellBounds.contains(static_cast<float>(mousePos.x), static_cast<float>(mousePos.y)))
                            {
                                currCell.type = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                    for (auto& row : array)
                    {
                        for (auto& currCell : row)
                        {
                            sf::FloatRect cellBounds = currCell.rect.getGlobalBounds();
                            if (cellBounds.contains(static_cast<float>(mousePos.x), static_cast<float>(mousePos.y)))
                            {
                                currCell.type = 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        // draw the cells

        // Update the array and set colors
        
        for (int y = size-1; y > 0; --y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
            {
                sf::Color color = sf::Color(0, 0, 0);
                if (array[x][y].type == 1)
                    color = sf::Color(255, 255, 0);
                if (array[x][y].type == 2)
                    color = sf::Color(0, 0, 255);

                array[x][y].update(array);
                array[x][y].setColor(color);
            }
        }
        window.clear();

        // Draw the cells
        for (int y = size-1; y > 0; --y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
            {
                window.draw(array[x][y].rect);
                array[x][y].moved = false;
            }
        }
        window.display();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

changing the direction doesnt seem to work as I expect it to, would it be because im doing everything in steps?

[here is a gif of it](https://imgur.com/a/bIyGMHh)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Or adding some debug prints? That way you would be able to see why it flashes.

Comment: i have went through the code and printed values, i think it is because the new cell happens while the old cell happens which makes it go all weird, but i dont quite know how i would be able to fix that issue. but then again, i am changing the values by setting 1 to water and the other to nothing so its all confusing and im not quite sure why this rapidly turns on and off.

Comment: Sorry to say this but the answer here is to write better quality code in the first place. Classes with well defined roles. Smaller functions, with meaningful names. No magic constants. etc. etc. When you are struggling to understand your own code it's not only hard for you, it's hard for anyone to help you. No help right now, but something to bear in mind for the future.

Comment: Thanks for the input @john ill try to rewrite everything and see if can solve the issue.

Comment: @SoulDaMeep A rewrite will definitely improve the code, it always does.

Comment: Ill keep that in mind for future projects @john do you know of any sources i could look at for writing cleaner, nice code?